# How to send the real-time personalization events data in Sitecore to external system like google analytics?

Tags: personalization

I need to capture the real-time personalization event in sitecore, capture the data and send to the google analytic through JavaScript API(using DataLayer).

**Scenarios**

Capture the event when Sitecore assign the pattern card to the visitor of the website and send this information to google analytic though JavaScript ? like unique visitor id, profile name, etc..

Capture the event when Sitecore hit the personalization rule and send this information to google analytics through JavaScript? Like UniqueVisitorID, ProfileName, PatternName, New rendering ID , or ruleId etc..

I just gone through the Bas Lijten blog, which is pretty much similar with my requirement.
http://blog.baslijten.com/realtime-personalization-monitoring-with-sitecore-and-google-analytics/

Any though, ideas or previous experience for the same type of requirement and solution?

Answer (score 0):

DataLayer.push is a way for you/developers/3rd-party-plugins to pass some useful data to the Data Layer. I have successfully implemented this on multiple Sitecore sites so I have an events report to measure how many users see a personalized component and click on a personalised link, button or component item.